# Error consumiendo webservice con SoapClient PHP

Tags: php, soap, webservice

Estoy tratando de consumir un web service con SoapClient PHP, he realizado varias pruebas pero la única respuesta que obtengo es el siguiente error:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the
>   exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server
>   trace logs.

Los desarrolladores del webservice me dicen que no es error de ellos. Le agradeceria a alguien si me puede ayudar con este error ya que no tengo mucha experiencia con webservice. Gracias de antemano.

El código php es el siguiente:

```
$WebService = "http://factulaar.grupolaar.com:9019/ClsWaybill.svc?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($WebService, array('trace' => 1));

$parametros = array(
    'ActualWeight' => '2',
    'Branch' => 'Quito',
    'ClientWeight' => '3',
    'Comments' => 'Testing WebService',
    'Company' => '10',
    'ContentSdtl' => 'Testing Contents',
    'CustomerId' => '01346',
    'DeclaredValue' => '100',

    'DeliveryAddress' => array(
        'AddressLine1' => 'Calle 1 22-13',
        'AddressLine2' => 'Calle 2',
        'City' => 'Cuenca',
        'Country' => 'Ecu',
        'Name' => 'Juan Pérez',
        'Phone' => '123456789',
        'State' => 'Azuay',
        'ZipCode' => '0',
    ),

    'ElectronicWeight' => '5',
    'GUIANumber' => '',
    'Height' => '10',
    'Idtrx' => '75',
    'Length' => '10',
    'Password' => 'TEST',
    'PickUpConsignee' => '52307',
    'PickupRequestDate' => '05/20/2016',
    'Pieces' => '1',
    'Service' => 'CRG',
    'UnitDimension' => 'CM',
    'Username' => 'WEBSERVICE',
    'Warehouseid' => 'QUITO',
    'Warehouseidloc' => '',
    'WeightUnit' => 'KG',
    'Width' => '10',
);

try
{
    $WS = new SoapClient($WebService, array("trace" => 1));
    $result = $WS->CreateWayBill($parametros1);
}
catch(SoapFault $exception)
{
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada, no pones que versión del protocolo SOAP estas usando 1_1 ó 1_2. Aunque eso podría no ser el problema ponlo. Después creo que el problema es tu arreglo. Si el WS esta en .Net, no puedes mandarle arrays de arrays, eso no existe en .NET. Para que se comuniquen debe ser así:

```
$WebService= new SoapClient("http://factulaar.grupolaar.com:9019/ClsWaybill.svc?wsdl", 
                    array('trace' => 1,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
$arreglo=array('parametro1'=>$parametro1,'parametro2'=>$parametro2, ...);//PuedenSerVarios
$respuesta = $WebService->__soapCall('CreateWayBill',array($arreglo));
```

Aún así podría tener algo este código ya que desconozco la documentación, pero creo que mas o menos sería así. Si mandas un array este debe de ir como un vector ya que .Net no entiende los arrays de PHP.

**Editada:**

Mira creo que seria así (hay que crear una clase WayBill con esas [propiedades](http://factulaar.grupolaar.com:9019/Help/html/0da1d2bd-4528-0bb1-511c-b602a51e72b5.htm)) y luego:

```
$WebService= new SoapClient("http://factulaar.grupolaar.com:9019/ClsWaybill.svc?wsdl", 
                    array('trace' => 1,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));    
$wayBill=new WayBill(); 
$wayBill->ActualWeight=$valor1; 
$wayBill->Branch=$valor2; 
//etc. Así con el resto de los campos 
$arreglo=array('objWayBillDetails'=>$wayBill);
$respuesta = $WebService->__soapCall('CreateWayBill',array($arreglo));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, si me proporcionaron el link con la documentación: [http://factulaar.grupolaar.com:9019/Help/html/d8186806-fcea-296e-c41c-2d459111f1be.htm](http://factulaar.grupolaar.com:9019/Help/html/d8186806-fcea-296e-c41c-2d459111f1be.htm).

Comment: Lo revise muy rapido porque ya me voy, pero segun lo que entiendo es que el metodo 'CreateWayBill' recibe un parametro 'WayBill' como dice aqui http://factulaar.grupolaar.com:9019/Help/html/0afccd75-3077-6469-82ef-a256f9172097.htm#! como dice ahi y ese objeto 'WayBill' tiene estas propiedades http://factulaar.grupolaar.com:9019/Help/html/0da1d2bd-4528-0bb1-511c-b602a51e72b5.htm 
Entonces en php hay que crear una clase WayBill con esas propiedades y luego:
$wayBill=new WayBill();
$wayBill->ActualWeight=$valor1;
$wayBill->Branch=$valor2;
etc.
$arreglo=array('objWayBillDetails'=>$wayBill);

Comment: y por ultimo $respuesta = $WebService->__soapCall('CreateWayBill',array($arreglo));
a $respuesta le haces un var_dump a ver que devuelve
y perdon por ponerlo así pero no se como marcar el código en los comentarios. Tambien pregunta que campos son requeridos y cuales opcionales, eso no lo dice la documentación y si te falta un campo requerido, eso puede hacer que truene

Comment: Bueno ya edite mi respuesta mejor.
Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, por fin logre consumir el web service.

Comment: ok, que bien que ya salio

Comment: Sugerencia: revisa que tienes permiso (de tu empleador, del cliente, del dueño del documento) para hacer pública esa documentación :/

Comment: Saludos tengo el mismo problema no me puedo conectar a este Web Services, aca esta la url WSDL: http://demo.quarzoweb.com/wsmallsolidarista/InventarioProductosWS.asmx. necesito usar el mismo codigo pero ya he probado y no me funciona. Si me pueden ayudar les agradeszco.

Comment: Tienes que leer también los comentarios, revisa con tu área de arquitectura que no te este bloqueando ningún firewall, revisa usando soapui que todavía conteste el WS