# Bad Request en un metodo PHP CURL para web-service SOAP

Tags: php, xml, webservice, soap, curl

Estoy intentando conectarme y enviar datos a un web service SOAP, y me genera el error Bad Request sin ningun detalle en el navegador.

Este es el codigo, incluida estructura XML:

```
$xml_data = 'XML data';

$headers = array(
"POST /ws_autos.asmx HTTP/1.1",
"Host: (web service url)",
"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
"SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/(web service method)\"",
"Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data)
);

$url = (web service url)?wsdl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);

$reply = curl_exec($ch); 



$xmli = new SimpleXMLElement($reply);


print_r($reply);

print_r($xmli);
```

Comment: y tu código php?? Si TU MISMO armaste ese xml con etiquetas soap:Body y soap:Envelope estas mal en todo ya que eso lo genera php automáticamente.

Comment: Es un codigo de ejemplo que encontre en esta misma pagina para aprender a utilizar web services, basicamente todo es codigo php, siendo el XML una variable (sin contar los headers) y estando abajo el metodo curl. Lo que no inclui fueron los tags ya que me parecieron irrelevantes al caso.

Comment: Mira esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12998/error-consumiendo-webservice-con-soapclient-php/13007#13007

Comment: Tengo entendido que los metodos SoapClient y Soap curl son diferentes, y esa solucion aplica al primero, descontando que el error en el hilo es otro. Si me equivoco me disculpo.

Comment: No existe un método `soap curl`. Soap es un protocolo y para Web Service tipo soap, php cuenta con funciones como `SoapClient`. `Curl` es una biblioteca que permite conectarse y comunicarse con diferentes tipos de servidores y diferentes tipos de protocolos, entre esos protocolos no esta soap. Debido a los protocolos que soporta `curl` generalmente se utiliza para consumir Web Service tipo `Rest`: http://php.net/manual/es/intro.curl.php